# Incompatible types using LatLng Google Maps

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio

First time making an android application and was trying to add polyline from Google directions onto Google maps.

Had imported:
`com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng`

I want to decode the Polyline points.
Tried to use `decode` from the PolylineEncoding class but this imports from:
`com.google.maps.model.LatLng`

This leads to incompatible types, so how do you make sure you're using compatible types? Or other ways to decode this polyline into a specific LatLng type without rewriting the algorithm?

Comment: are you trying to make route from one place to other place

Comment: @SSALPHAX ya! i'm trying to figure out what i should be using for this.
Now decoded it using PolyUtil



so n

Answer (score 0):

Try this pass your result in the drawPath() method

```
 public void drawPath(String result) {
    if (line != null) {
        googleMap.clear();
    }
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Dloca));
    //googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(loc));
    try {
        // Tranform the string into a json object
        final JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONArray routeArray = json.getJSONArray("routes");
        JSONObject routes = routeArray.getJSONObject(0);
        JSONObject overviewPolylines = routes
                .getJSONObject("overview_polyline");
        String encodedString = overviewPolylines.getString("points");
        List<LatLng> list = decodePoly(encodedString);

        for (int z = 0; z < list.size() - 1; z++) {
            LatLng src = list.get(z);
            LatLng dest = list.get(z + 1);
            line = googleMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                    .add(new LatLng(src.latitude, src.longitude),
                            new LatLng(dest.latitude, dest.longitude))
                    .width(5).color(Color.BLUE).geodesic(true));
        }

        dialog.dismiss();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private List<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {

    List<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
    int lat = 0, lng = 0;

    while (index < len) {
        int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lat += dlat;

        shift = 0;
        result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lng += dlng;

        LatLng p = new LatLng((((double) lat / 1E5)),
                (((double) lng / 1E5)));
        poly.add(p);
    }

    return poly;
}
```

This code will return you line in google map according to your route source and destination location.

Comment: So I wanted to avoid re-writing this method since what would be the point when it's part of the maps api.

I don't think I was clear in my question, but my initial problem was understanding why google packages are using different LatLng types. In the end i used something similar to:

`import com.google.maps.android.PolyUtil
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng
...
List<LatLng> directions = PolyUtil.decode(polylineString); 
PolylineOptions p = new PolylineOptions();
p.addAll(directions);
googleMap.addPolyline(p);
...`